# PHP fputcsv encoding

Tags: php, csv, encoding, export-to-csv

I create csv file with fputcsv. I want csv file to be in windows1251 ecnding. But can't find the solution. How can I do that? 
Cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Default encoding for an excel file is machine specific ANSI, mainly `windows1252`. But since you are creating that file and maybe inserting UTF-8 characters, that file is not going to be handled ok.

You could use `iconv()` when creating the file. Eg:

```
function encodeCSV(&$value, $key){
    $value = iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $value);
}
array_walk($values, 'encodeCSV');
```

Comment: When I use this method I have this error: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Comment: *"Default encoding for a csv file is windows1251"*...?!?! Who set this default?

Comment: Just woke up :), `windows1252` for EN-US

Comment: Please change the answer code to reflect Windows-1252 instead of Windows-1251

Comment: @rayVenues changed :)

Answer (score 12):

It's Working: Enjoy
use this before fputcsv:

```
$line = array_map("utf8_decode", $line);
```

Comment: underrated comment!

Comment: That's  completely wrong. `utf8_decode` cannot convert UTF-8 to windows1251. See PHP documentation.

Comment: @ragol utf8_decode: Converts a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1. that resolves the issue...
Please check  https://www.typeerror.org/docs/php/function.utf8-decode

Comment: @ArslanTabassum The question was about Windows1251 encoding, not ISO-8859-1. They are different. `utf8_decode` and `utf8_encode` functions only work with ISO-8859-1. Using them for anything else is wrong. That is also stated as a note in the documentation.  Also this function is deprecated in the upcoming PHP 8.2.0.

Answer (score 6):

The file will be in whatever encoding your strings are in. PHP strings are raw byte arrays, their encodings depends on wherever the bytes came from. If you just read them from your source code files, they're in whatever you saved your source code as. If they're from a database, they're in whatever encoding the database connection was set to.

If you need to convert from one encoding to another, use [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv). If you need more in-depth information, see here:

- [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)
- [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: What if I choose an encoding where the `,` and `"` used in the CSV files are encoded differently, like UTF-16?

Comment: Then supply UTF-16 encoded `"` and `,` to `fputcsv` as parameters. (Haven't actually tried it though, but would be my first attempt.)

Comment: This reply and reading through the articles saved my day. Thank you!

Comment: This one is a more usefull link to iconv: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 6):

```
fputs( $fp, $bom = chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) );
```

Try this it worked for me!!!

Comment: Yup, first `fputs` like above and then `fputcsv` right after that fixed it for me, too. BOM is the byte order mark which Excel needs to display umlauts and special character correctly, especially on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Try the iconv function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

To transform the members of the array you're passing to the fputcsv function to the encoding you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string), 'Windows-1252//TRANSLIT', $string);
```

Comment: It would help readers if you added further explanation to your answer so they could see the value in your answer compared to the other solution choices. Use [edit] to improve your answer.