# PHP 7: Query output to Text File Questions (FIeld Headers and Skipping a Comma after last column)

Tags: php

I've very new to PHP and trying to re-create some code I had in another language.   The current version of PHP I'm working with is 7.17.

Right now, I'm trying to re-create a simple function of opening a MySQL query as a comma deliminated text file where there is no comma after the last column (just a line break).   I'm trying to figure out two things right now to finish this piece of code.

1. How do I insert the query column headers at the top of the data output (right now only the data is output, not the column headers).
2. At the line "fwrite($output,  $value.',');", I'm trying to figure out how to not add the comma after the last field (how to skip adding the comma after the last column of data).

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=cars.txt');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    while ($row = getRow($result)) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            fwrite($output,  $value.',');
        }
        fwrite($output, "\r\n");
    }
    fclose($output);

    exit;

}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a CSV file, so why not use PHP's built in CSV handling functionality ([fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)), like so:

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

while ($row = getRow($result)) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}

fclose($output);
```

This way PHP does all the heavy lifting for you.

Edited based upon comment.

You could try using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488954/php-fputcsv-encoding) to handle the encoding of the values before converting to CSV and then set the file encoding in the HTTP header to `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');`.

Also `fputcsv` allows you to change the delimiter, enclosure and escape characters if they were causing you issues.

Otherwise just do:

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

while ($row = getRow($result)) {
    $line = implode(', ', $row);
    fwrite($output, $line);
}

fclose($output);
```

Comment: The file being generated is used to directly upload into a piece of equipment where I was having problems with the formatting of CSV files and I was trying to find another working solution other than a CSV output (ANSI vs Unicode and where real line breaks are needed)..